# RSelenium can't select an option from a drop-down menu

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, web-crawler, rselenium

I'm trying to select an option from a drop-down menu using RSelenium. Although my codes can find and click elements without an error warning, the option is not actually selected - the page still uses the default option.

The website I'm trying to scrape is:

```
url <- 'https://wrlc-gu.primo.exlibrisgroup.com/discovery/search?vid=01WRLC_GUNIV:01WRLC_GUNIV&mode=advanced'
remDr$navigate(url)
```

The codes I use to find and click the drop-down menu are:

```
# activate the first drop-down menu
frame <- remDr$findElement('xpath', '/html/body/primo-explore/div/prm-explore-main/div/prm-search-bar/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/prm-advanced-search/form/div/div[2]/md-card[1]/div[1]/fieldset/div[1]/md-input-container[1]/md-select')
frame$clickElement
Sys.sleep(2)
# choose the third option (creator/author)
remDr$findElement('css', '#select_option_51')$clickElement
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

There is no error warning, but the screenshot shows the option is not selected after the codes. I am using chrome via docker.

I'm very new to web-crawling and appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `xpath` worked.

```
remDr$findElement(using ="xpath", '//*[@id="select_option_55"]/div[1]/span')$clickElement()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Nad, thanks for your answer! I tried the solution on my machine but it didn't work out :(... maybe there is some issue with my settings/browser?

Comment: I used `firefox` browser without docker. Why not try running `chrome` outside docker?